# why accessing my hostname doesn't work like by IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, hyper-v

I'm new in microsoft server administration, please forgive me in advance

I have a Hyper-V Windows Server 2012 instance with IIS enabled.

I create a website on it with a custom name and a Application under it

everything works great when I access the website in the VM or from my Windows 10 Host PC

What I can't understand is, why is it only accessible by IP "http://ip/myapplication" ? why am I not able to access it by the VM hostname?

After searching on web I came across that I need a DNS server.

I confess that the concept of DNS is hard to understand for me (sorry) but even harder to get is: why the hell do I need a whole new server address this issue?

please help, be nice with a beginner

Comment: Side note, It's also best practice to segment certain roles, for instance, a Hyper-V server is recommended to only run the Hyper-V role, and should not have IIS loaded on it. You may need to create a virtual machine to host IIS as well as create a domain controller with an AD integrated DNS environment. [see best practices article here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/best-practices-analyzer/hyper-v-should-be-the-only-enabled-role?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a local DNS server will solve your problem, there's a simpler way: edit your hosts file.  You can do this manually with any text editor, or you can use a tool such as [Hostman](http://www.abelhadigital.com/hostsman) to do it for you (don't forget to run it *as administrator*).

Your hosts file keeps track of hostname IP address pairs connected to your system.  Having a local DNS server does this automatically for you, but yes, it's much more complicated to set-up and maintain (although it's relatively straightforward with Windows Server).  DNS registration is only necessary if you want your machine**s** to be accessible by hostname or domain name over the Internet.  You can still, however, access a single machine by domain name on your local network from the Internet without running a *local* DNS server (by using port-forwarding, domain registration still required).

[Here's a great tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) that explains how to edit your hosts file in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

DNS is a distributed lookup database dedicated to a name hierarchy we know as *domain names*.  The top level is the root.  It has no name, so a lone dot is used.  At that level is `com` and `net`.  These make for the next level which has millions of names and is where yours would be.  You need to get your name put there.  This process is a shared system (details we do not need to learn) called *domain registration*.  You need to visit one of the hundreds of *domain registration agents* and register your name.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is most likely set to use a DNS server of your router / modem and that most likely points to a public ISP such as Comcast, 75.75.75.75 or Google, 8.8.8.8, when you try to resolve http://hostname/myapplication with your web browser your DNS client is performing a lookup because it does not know about that hostname. (although you can probably resolve the IP using ARP)

You can manually edit your host file as specified, or setup a DNS server to resolve that primary zone.